# Card flip animation in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have tired to make a flip card in android.Please make an image view,when I click on,it flip like
[image: this]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final ObjectAnimator oa1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleX", 1f, 0f);
        final ObjectAnimator oa2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "scaleX", 0f, 1f);
        oa1.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        oa2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        oa1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.frontSide);
                oa2.start();
            }
        });
        oa1.start();
    }
});
```

This animation doesn't have any depth but maybe you will like it.

You can also set animation duration with

```
oa1.setDuration(1000);
oa2.setDuration(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Cahid Enes Keleş. your rock

Comment: please make one ObjectAnimator not two.Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot, I have been thinking, "How about if I would like to back the image1 again?". I mean is this only one-time flip? Or able to change from image2 to image1 by another click? How can I implement it?

Comment: You can set a flag to 1 in one case and 0 in the other case, and check whether the flag is 1 or 0 before you make the animation and act accordingly.

Answer (score 31):

[Property Animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (not to be confused with the older View Animation) are quite powerful :

```
final View v = <the_image_view>;

// first quarter turn
v.animate().withLayer()
        .rotationY(90)
        .setDuration(300)
        .withEndAction(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {

                        <change the image...>

                        // second quarter turn
                        v.setRotationY(-90);
                        v.animate().withLayer()
                                .rotationY(0)
                                .setDuration(300)
                                .start();
                    }
                }
        ).start();
```

You can adjust the perspective effect with [View.setCameraDistance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setCameraDistance(float))

Comment: It worked. My "card" image was too big so I used the setCameraDistance suggestion to avoid card being "cut" because too near to the screen:  
`float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;  float distance = ivPreview.getCameraDistance() * (scale + (scale / 3));
ivPreview.setCameraDistance(distance);  `

Comment: Many thanks! But instead `View` need to use `ImageView`!