# How to make a flip animation using XML

Tags: android

Basically what I want to do is the animation of a card that turns.
I have three ImageButton and I need an animation that makes them flip when I press them and then after one or two second make the one pressed disappear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Card flip animation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111262/card-flip-animation-in-android)

Comment: But it is closed

Comment: It has an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46111960/5314844

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey there you can make this animation using **XML**

Just follow these step

> 1) Create anim folder in you res directory
>
> 2) Add resource file for you animation for **example** *flip_animation*.xml
>
> 3) Add this code to your animation file

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="-1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"/>
<scale
        android:fromXScale="-1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1000"/>
```

And then you can call it in you programming section on any view

In Kotlin you can do

```
 val animationUtils = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flip_animation)
        buttonAnimation.startAnimation(animationUtils)
```

In Java you can do

```
AnimationUtils animationUtils = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.flip_animation);
Button buttonAnimation = findViewById(R.id.buttonAnimation);
buttonAnimation.startAnimation(animationUtils)
```

This is how you can flip a view horizontally if you want vertical one you can try this either.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="-1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"/>
<scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="-1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1000"/>
```

**And simple if you want some fun flip **

> You can try this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="-1"
        android:fromYScale="-1"
        android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="500"/>
<scale
        android:fromXScale="-1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="-1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1000"/>
```